# What happens if I use sessionStorage.getItem("data-theme"); if "data-theme" has not been defined yet?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I grabbed javascript code from the internet that creates a button to toggle dark mode on and off and it works perfectly fine. Here I'll paste only the relevant chunk of what I've written so far:

```
    <script>
    // Wait for document to load
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    
    //store in a variable whatever the data-theme is in the sessionStorage
    var sessionVariable = sessionStorage.getItem("data-theme");
    
    /*
    // if it doesnt exist (which is null, i think) then it sets the data-theme value to light
    if string(sessionVariable) == "null"{
        document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");   
    // if it does exist, which means data-theme is either dark or light, then it sets it to that
    } else{
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", string(sessionVariable))
    }
    */
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "light") //THIS IS THE LINE THAT WORKS, I WOULD LIKE TO REMOVE IT FOR THE COMMENTED OUT CODE ABOVE

    // Get our button switcher
    var themeSwitcher = document.getElementById("theme-switcher");

    // When our button gets clicked
    themeSwitcher.onclick = function() {
    
    // Get the current selected theme, on the first run  it should be `light`
    var currentTheme = document.documentElement.getAttribute("data-theme");
    
    // Switch between `dark` and `light`
    var switchToTheme = currentTheme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark";
    
    sessionStorage.setItem("data-theme", "currentTheme"); //store in the sessionStorage whatever the data-theme's value is (the currentTheme)

    // Set our current theme to the new one
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", switchToTheme);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is add sessionStorage functionality to it. As you can see at the beginning I commented out a huge chunk of code: I think that should work but it doesnt, and the original unedited line that I grabbed from the internet is the one I said I want to replace.

So, my logic is, when the page is opened for the first time, clearly there is no "data-theme" stored on the sessionStorage. And when the second javascript line tries to getItem("data-theme"), it should return "null", right?. Then I make it so that if data-theme is null (which means its not been defined yet) it sets the theme to light (default mode), but if it is indeed defined then it sets it to whatever it is (either light or dark)

Yet when I erase the line that I want to delete and un-comment out that chunk of code, the button stops working alltogether. I suppose its because theres something wrong with my "if" statements. What is it? Is the sessionVariable not "null" when its not been defined yet?

Comment: `What happens if I use sessionStorage.getItem("data-theme"); if "data-theme" has not been defined yet?` what have you observed happens?

Comment: From what I could find in the internet, it should set the value of "data-theme" to "null" because its not been defined yet, maybe the user is opening the page for the first time.

But if this is true then why are my if statements not working? i dont see anything particularly wrong with them

Comment: `it should set the value` ... getItem **returns** a value, it does not **set** a value - do your `if statements` account for the fact that `sessionVariable` could be `null`?

Comment: The value you get for an undefined sessionStorage variable is `null` and _not_ `"null"`. Leave out your quotation marks (`"`) and it should work.

Comment: what you should be doing is `var sessionVariable = sessionStorage.getItem("data-theme")??'light';` - thereby defining that `light` is the default

Comment: @CarstenMassmann - `String(null) === "null"` - that's the comparison (albeit invalid syntax) in the commented code

Comment: I see the issue ... `sessionStorage.setItem("data-theme", "currentTheme");` ... stores the string `"currentTheme"` ... not the value of the variable of that name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line

```
if string(sessionVariable) == "null"{
```

should be changed to

```
if (sessionVariable === "null"){
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrong thing with your "if" is that, you are comparing it with string null not actual null
i.e.

```
"null" /* this is string */
```

try

```
if(sessionVariable === null)
```

here null is absence of any value